# RMD in R Studio Desktop

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

How do I open an RMD file in the desktop version of R studio?

I clicked on File and did not find the option for New File, and rmarkdown file. In the cloud version of r studio, it gives the option for File >> New File >> R Markdown.

Comment: What version of RStudio are you using? Do you have the `rmarkdown` package installed on your machine? What options do you see? Can you take a screen shot to show us what you are seeing?

Comment: I am using version 4.2.3 of R Studio Desktop. I installed the r markdown package using the install.packages function